# nth derivative of: $F(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes

I've gotten this function from probability generating functions, and I want to calculate it's nth derivative (With respect to $x$).

This is:
$$F(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Is there a practical way to do it?

Or for another approach, I just need the derivatives calculated in $x=0$, to calculate it's MacLaurin series. Any practical way to do it?

Comment: First derivative is $0$ at $0$, second derivative is $-1$, third derivative is $0$, then $3$, $0$, $45$, $0$, $1575$, $0$..... interesting pattern here. (there doesn't seem to be an obvious pattern, if it exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ using the binomial theorem: you'll get something like
$$ \sqrt{1-x^2}=\sum_{k\geqslant 0} (-x)^{2k} \binom{1/2}{k},  $$
which you can then expand out into a product.

Comment: Oh. That's it. I know how to do the rest, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

let $g(x)=(1-x)^\frac 12$

$$g'(x)=-\frac 12 (1-x)^{-\frac 12} \\
g''(x)=-\frac 12 \frac 12 (1-x)^{-\frac 32} \\
g'''(x)=-\frac 32 \frac 12 \frac 12 (1-x)^{-\frac 52} \\
g^{(4)}(x)=-\frac 52\frac 32 \frac 12 \frac 12 (1-x)^{-\frac 72} \\
g^{(5)}(x)=-\frac 72\frac 52\frac 32 \frac 12 \frac 12 (1-x)^{-\frac 92} \\
$$

so 
$$g^{(n)}(x)=-\frac {1}{2^n} (2n-3)(2n-5)(2n-7) ... (5)(3)(1) (1-x)^{-\frac{2n-1}{2} }    \\
$$

$$g^{(n)}(0)=-\frac {1}{2^n} (2n-3)(2n-5)(2n-7) ... (5)(3)(1) 
\\ = -\frac {1}{2^n} \frac{(2n-3)!}{(2n-2)(2n-4)(2n-6) ... (4)(2)}
\\ = -\frac {1}{2^n} \frac{(2n-3)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}
\\ = -\frac {1}{2^{2n-1}} \frac{(2n-3)!}{(n-1)!}
$$

You should be able to complete this knowing that $F(x)=1-g(x^2)$

Comment: Thanks, it's already done using the binomial series (The answer I got is the same), but it's interesting to see how to get a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Calculate $F'(x),F''(x),F^{(3)}(x)$ and try to find a pattern. Prove it using induction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v=v(x)=1-x^2$.
For $k\ge0$, making use of the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\bigl(\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\bigr)^{(k)}
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\operatorname{d}^j\sqrt{v}\,}{\operatorname{d} v^j}B_{k,j}(-2x,-2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\biggl\langle\frac12\biggr\rangle_jv^{1/2-j} (-1)^j2^jB_{k,j}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\biggl\langle\frac12\biggr\rangle_j \bigl(1-x^2\bigr)^{1/2-j} (-1)^j2^j \frac{1}{2^{k-j}}\frac{k!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}x^{2j-k}\\
&=-\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\frac{k!}{(2x)^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{2^{j}(2j-3)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}.
\end{align*}
Consequently, we acquire
\begin{equation}
F^{(k)}(x)=\bigl(1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\bigr)^{(k)}
=\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\frac{k!}{(2x)^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{2^{j}(2j-3)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}, \quad k\ge0.
\end{equation}

References

1. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
2. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
3. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.