# $N$th derivative of $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I was wondering if there was any formula for the nth derivative of $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$ and by an easy extension $-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$. What would be even better is a Taylor series for the function at point $a$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is expressible with Faà di Bruno's formula using the composition of $1-x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ but it isn't a closed form.

Comment: See the WolframAlpha [**output**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bsqrt(1-x%5E2),%7Bx,n%7D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

At https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657792, there is an answer:
\begin{equation*}
\bigl(\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\bigr)^{(k)}
=-\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\frac{k!}{(2x)^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{2^{j}(2j-3)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}.
\end{equation*}